# Persist UITableViewCell background color on scrolling tableViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a **UITableView**, when the user taps a cell it turns grey to indicate it is complete. However when the cell is scrolled out of view, when it comes back into view it has returned to its default background colour erasing the users interaction.

Is there a way to persist the cell tapped background color on scrolling?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? TodaysRoutineTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("Unexpected Index Path")
     }
     cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.customBackgroundGraphite()
     cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
     configure(cell, at: indexPath)
     return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {

        if cell.backgroundColor == UIColor.customExerciseDoneCellColor() {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.customBackgroundGraphite()
        } else if cell.backgroundColor == UIColor.customBackgroundGraphite() {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.customExerciseDoneCellColor()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maintain the state in your model class and use the model class to populate the cell. Separate the view from your model.

Comment: You are reusing the cells with `tableView.dequeueReusableCell`. Which means the same cells are being re-used to show different data on scroll/reload. How do you suppose the reused cell is to remember it was selected before unless you provide it that info?

Comment: I know this is the issue, im here looking for the solution...

Comment: I gave you the solution in the first comment. Create a Model class, keep a flag in model class, set background color based on it. Set the array of your modelclasses to be datasource of your tableview. MVC means separation of Model, View and Controller.

Comment: the data that populates the table is already an array from a core data entity, is it best to use that and add the 'is done' field to it and write / unwrite it as needed and load that cells background based on that? Seems a bit heavy duty, would UserDefaults not be usable here?

Comment: NSUserdefaults should never be used like that. That will leave huge room open for errors in your app. Also yes you can load your tableView directly from coredata. [See here for example](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial)

Comment: Alright ill look into doing it this way, I already have the coredata populating the table, none of thats an issue, literally just persisting background colouration. i assume im doing ot have to execute a coredata save every time a user taps or untaps a cell? and reload the table data? still seems overkill

Answer (score -1):

The issue is when you scroll after selecting the cell, the selected colour is not retained isn't it??

Cell for row delegate is called whenever you scroll. So even though you set background in Did select delegate its changed when Cell for row is called.

In order to tackle this situation add a boolean to tableview cell and when you select the cell change the boolean status.

In cell for row add this:

```
if cell.CheckBoolean == true{
    cell.backgroundcolor = UI.color()
}else{
    cell.backgroungcolor = UI.color()
}
```

In did select delegate :
change the value of that boolean and reload the table view

Comment: in the OP i already stated this was the issue, looking for the solution...

Comment: SahyadriChava, I have edited the answer hope this can be the solution.